# Maven problem porting build from linux to windows

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am porting a project build from linux to windows.  I am running into problems with the following piece of my pom.xml

I replaced

```
  <execution>
    <id>rm -rf node_modules/</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>initialize</phase>
    <configuration>
      <executable>rm</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-fr</argument>
        <argument>node_modules/</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

With

```
<execution>
    <id>rm -rf node_modules/</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>initialize</phase>
    <configuration>
        <executable>rmdir</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>.\node_modules\</argument>
            <argument>/S</argument>
            <argument>/Q</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

The first works under linux but fails under windows, so I figured use the appropriate cmd.exe commands.  This however is failing with a file not found the directory exists so my assumption is that it is the command that is failing.
I also tried the powershell command  Remove-Item with appropriate arguments this also failed, I have also tried changing the argument order also a no go.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full `pom.xml` file to your question. Also add the full complete error message you get to your question as well. Run your maven command with the `-X` argument to get more debug output from the execution. Have you tried using the `maven-antrun-plugin` plugin? It has a dedicated [<delete>](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm` is a Linux executable, but `rmdir` is not a Windows executable: it is a command. The correct executable is `CMD` with `/c rmdir` as the first two arguments. However the `maven-antrun-plugin` suggested above and the `maven-clean-plugin` are better choices because the result will work both with Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm guessing the executable not being pwsh is why the powershell was also failing.  As soon as I have a moment I am going to try your suggestion.